# Adjust the width of an xib element using autolayout

Tags: ios, xcode, xib, uiinterfaceorientation, autolayout

I am trying to learn autolayout . The following is the simple UIView elements that i am trying to implement using autolayout . The constraints are added in the xib. Everything works fine in the portrait mode, but in the landscape mode the blue color item is squished .

1. How do i make this blue color item make to have some more height space in landscape mode.
2. How do we make the blue color item and the green color item widths in the ration (30:70) or (40:60)

Do i have to make constraint outlets and define the values at runtime.

[image: Portrait][image: Landscape]

Comment: Maybe you need to set content compression resistance to "required" for your blue view.

Comment: @Zhang I tried that. No change . All are the colored elements in the xib are just UIView for now

Answer (score 1):

You've set fixed heights for the red block, the brown block, the distance between them and the distance between the blue and red blocks and the container. There's no alternative but to squish the blue block.

What do you want to happen? Should the brown block get shorter? Should the red block? Then you should remove the height constraints. Perhaps you could set the brown and blue blocks to have equal heights.

I'm not entirely sure what you mean in your second question. If you want the ratio of the green block width to the blue block width to be 70:30, then set a constraint for equal widths and then edit the multiplier. For example, blue width equals green width * 3/7. You can actually set the multiplier using ratio syntax (70:30) in IB.

Comment: Thank you Ken. Third point worked greatly (ratio relation). Regarding the brown block and the blue block what i want is, when in the landscape mode , i need that to have equal widths or some ratio.

Comment: What is the role of multiplier and constants in this case

Comment: I assume you meant heights, not widths. OK, so set a constraint between the two heights at whatever ratio you like. You will have to remove the constraint that sets a fixed height on the brown block. You will need constraints to keep the spacing between the red block and the brown block constant and, similarly, the spacing between the brown block and the blue block. (It's hard to tell from your screenshot. You may already have those.)

Comment: Thanks Ken . I am happy to find some one out there having good knowledge on autolayout